# Navigation links to posts in current term shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, templates, terms, navigation

I have created a custom post type 'property' on my WordPress site with a taxonomy of 'property-category'.
I have a php snippet to display the next and previous posts in the CPT of the current term eg. the next Property in the same category.

```
previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE, ' ', 'property-category' );
```

However, I need to place this in a module in a page builder, so I thought I could make a shortcode out of it. But that’s where I’m getting stuck.

I’ve tried to create my own shortcode by adding this to the functions file,

```
function fivehats_previous_post() {
previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE, ' ', 'property-category' );
}
add_shortcode( 'fh_prev', 'fivehats_previous_post' );
```

I placed `[fh_prev]` in the module on the page template for single-property but I seem to be missing a step, as the shortcode is not out-putting anything.

Does anybody have any suggestions as why that's not working, or even a different solution to get the nav links to properties within the current category to work?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to echo get_previous_post_link as this is what is called when you set function previous_post_link.

```
function fivehats_previous_post() {
// You need to echo it out for it to display in the page
echo get_previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE, ' ', 'property-category' );
}
add_shortcode( 'fh_prev', 'fivehats_previous_post' );
```